How to I save an AudioKit MIDIFile to permanent file in iOS using Swift
I am creating a music app using SwiftUI with AudioKit. The app captures MIDI input from a keyboard and creates a MIDIFile which I want save to the file system so that it can be read into other music apps such as Musescore or GarageBand. Despite much Googling have not been able to find how to do this.
Would appreciate any guidance/links which shows how to do this.
